# WSO2 Governance Registry: How to avoid registry tables growth?

Tags: wso2

We are using the WSO2 Carbon / WSO2 Governance Registry for one of our products and noticed a abnormal database growth. It turned out that the constant groth is related to [REGISTRY-3919](https://wso2.org/jira/projects/REGISTRY/issues/REGISTRY-3919).

This issue is marked as *resolved* with resolution *postponed*. But this is not a resolution for productive systems. Is any other WSO2 product user facing this problem and has a proper resolution for the constant database growth?

Comment: Can you confirm all the WSO2 products you are using? I might be able to help you to clean old registry properties.

Comment: @Chandana: Thank you very much for your offer! Atm we are already cleaning the database by removing the old registry properties via cronjob. We are seeking for a "proper fix", even if it involves patching and recompiling some components.

Comment: Since this is a design issue for Carbon 4 based product stack, there is no alternative approach than cleaning old registry properties.

Comment: @Chandana: is there any other known workaround for this issue? We are using it in an clustered / replicated percona setup and the registry tables issuing an extraordinary high binlog. O_o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like stated in comments, this is a design issue. We ended up using [pt-archiver](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-archiver.html) in a cronjob
to clean orphaned registry properties from our percona cluster.

```
pt-archiver \
    --run-time 4h \
    --progress 10000 \
    --limit 2000 \
    --no-check-charset \
    --source h=<hostname>,D=<database>,t=REG_RESOURCE_PROPERTY \
    --purge \
    --where '(REG_VERSION, REG_TENANT_ID) NOT IN (SELECT REG_VERSION, REG_TENANT_ID FROM REG_RESOURCE)'
```